# Come to my office. Will do

Tags: do-support

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Pages 100-101):

> There is, however, an important difference – in code ***do*** is not limited to primary forms, and where secondary forms are involved versions with and without ***do*** are in alternation, not mutually exclusive: 
> [32] VERSION WITHOUT *DO* ------- VERSION WITH *DO* 
> i a. *I’ve seen it; Pat may h̲a̲v̲e̲ too.* b. %*I’ve seen it; Pat may h̲a̲v̲e̲ d̲o̲n̲e̲ too.* 
> ii a. *I haven’t read it but I w̲i̲l̲l̲ soon.* b. %*I haven’t read it but I w̲i̲l̲l̲ ̲d̲o̲ soon.* 
> As indicated by the % annotation, the [b] versions are not admissible to all speakers: BrE speakers accept such forms while AmE speakers mainly reject them. It is plausible to suggest that correlating with the difference in admissibility of these [b] versions is a difference in the grammatical status of do in code. In BrE the ***do*** of code constructions is a pro-form: in [31ib] (*I hated it and Pat d̲i̲d̲ too.*) and [32ib/iib] reduction is achieved not by ellipsis but by the substitution of a verb that stands for the whole antecedent VP. [...]

> In the dialect where examples like [32] are inadmissible, the ***do*** used in code is restricted to primary forms and can therefore be assimilated to the supportive ***do*** used in primary verbal negation, inversion, and emphasis. Here, then, [31ib] (*I hated it and Pat d̲i̲d̲ too.*) will be elliptical, like [31iia] (*I a̲m̲ well and Pat i̲s̲ too*). It differs in that reinstatement of the ellipted material requires that ***do*** be dropped: the full form is *I h̲a̲t̲e̲d̲ i̲t̲ and Pat h̲a̲t̲e̲d̲ ̲i̲t̲ too*, not **I hated it and Pat did hate it too*. But this is a general property of the ***do***-support constructions: if we change interrogative *Did he hate it?* into its declarative counterpart we likewise drop ***do*** (*He hated it*). For this dialect, then, the code construction always involves ellipsis. Leaving aside the case where we have stranding of the infinitival marker *to*, it is a matter of ellipting the complement of an auxiliary verb, and if the full form contains no auxiliary then ***do*** must be inserted to permit complement ellipsis to apply.

But even in AmE, you can use *do* as follows:

> A: *Come to my office in the afternoon.* 
> B: *Will do.*

Here, *do* is in a secondary form and still stands for the whole antecedent VP *come to your office in the afternoon*. Is *Will do* sort of an outlier? Or are there other such examples in AmE?

Comment: I think it's more or less a fixed phrase, since "I will do" would obviously be ungrammatical as a replacement for "Will do" in the dialogue you mention.

Comment: Note also that, while "I won't do so" could be a valid response (in place of "Will do"), the phrase "Won't do" would clearly be wrong. (Though I suppose "Won't do so" doesn't really work there either.)

Comment: @alphabet — We have *No can do* for the negative. But both that and *Will do* are clearly idiomatic/colloquial.

Comment: @TinfoilHat "No can do" is a bit special. As I recall, like "Long time no see," it's originally a calque from Chinese.

Comment: @alphabet — They're both special.

Comment: "Can do" is sometimes used, and has become an [adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can-do). "How do" is a greeting in some dialects - internet says Yorkshire and US rural. "To-do" or "to do" have various uses (both fusses and lists). There are lots of "do" idioms.

Comment: @StuartF I do declare, we do have a bunch of them! (mainly southern dialect, female.)

Comment: What difference might it make if you dropped all down to and including '… even in AmE, you can use do as follows:…'?

The example is too obviously an artificial construction to be taken seriously.

When did you here any English speaker say 'Come to my office in the afternoon'?

Similarly, 'Will do' is fine in idiom but it has not place in grammar. Which interests you most?

Broadly, 'will do' is at best slang, standing in for 'Yes, I will…'